# how to generate unique session ID without the use of session_id()?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I want to generate a  session ID. This unique sessionId represents some different data for every different user.

My code till now:

1. onclick and onload of a page I call a function `create_session_id();`

   ```
   function create_session_id() {
       // This function sends a string to a PHP page using ajax post.
   }
   ```
2. On my PHP page, I receive this data and then insert it:

   ```
   session_start();
   $a = session_id();
   $object->insert_sessionid($a);
   ```

### My Question

Is it possible to use only `session_start()` (no `session_id()`) and store some unique session ID value that I can use later when I fetch data and throw data to my web page. I don’t want any clicks to register sessionid. It should happen on page load and without any function `create_session_id()`.

I am thinking to bring some cookies in to the picture.

Note: My website doesn’t allow login.

Comment: uh, if you're thinking of bring in cookies, you should realize that PHP sessions by default use cookies anyways. So just use a session_start(), then use `session_id()` to get the session ID that was created (or is being reused).

Comment: You can use some kind of counter?

Comment: session_start() can occur on any php page without the need for any additional interaction with the user beyond them simply requesting the page. BUT -- not using a "login" and simply using cookies is inherently insecure, and user's clearing their cookies would generate a new "unique" session, so you would not be able to track a "user" by this, only repeat sessions from the same browser that have accepted and not cleared the cookies.

Comment: @GintasK He probably could, but wouldn't that cause a potential security threat, as session ids could be easily guessed?

Comment: @MarcB:i dont need to reuse session id..The thing is am tracking user behaviour on a website.So every user that comes on website landing page should be given a session id.obviously every user behaviour will be different.I am told that you can do this just by using session_start().Can you give me a small snippet.The thing is i  dont need a function like create_session_id() and want to generate session id on load??how to do that?

Comment: uh, session_id() creates a random Id for any new users and stores it in a client-side cookie. Returning users will send over the ID they were assigned and session_start() will use that ID. You don't have to do ANYTHING to get this behavior, it's standard PHP.

Answer (score 5):

use a function like

```
function createRandomVal($val){
      $chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,-";
      srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
      $i = 0;
      $pass = '' ;
      while ($i<=$val) 
    {
        $num  = rand() % 33;
        $tmp  = substr($chars, $num, 1);
        $pass = $pass . $tmp;
        $i++;
      }
    return $pass;
    }
```

and pass return value in session id

Comment: I appreciate your effort but as i said,i dont want to create a function.have a look at comments!!!

Comment: without calling any event or function, on load you have to call some function or initiate a process that will generate the session value for you

Comment: What a waste of cpu cycles. Why not just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php and get a randoms string with FAR better characteristics?

Comment: is that possible..IF i write session_start() on the first line of my html home page,then what should i do next

Comment: @MarcB:I know what session id does.I have used that also.just want to ask you without using session_id(),there is no way we can generate unique session_id?

Answer (score 1):

The above code is a little bit buggy since `user669677` has edited it.

Here is the proper code:

```
function createRandomVal($val) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,-";
    srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
    $i = 0;
    $pass = '';
    while ($i < $val) {
        $num = rand() % 64;
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
        $pass = $pass . $tmp;
        $i++;
    }
    return $pass;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you fixing the minor bug in the above code but a slightly better way would be to use: 

```$num = rand() % strlen($chars);``` 

This way the end developer can just define the characters.

Comment: BEWARE! If the microtime is same at different runtimes, than the generated string will be same. If  uniqueness is important do not use this function. Don't think this is a secure way of generating session ids